# Is there a free, actively developed IRC client for Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, software-recommendation, chat

So far I've been able to find only outdated clients, which are either abandoned years ago or they are currently developed but only for newer systems, or commercial.

Is there a free<sup>1</sup> client actively developed for Snow Leopard?

<sup>1</sup> Free "as in beer", though, of course, I'd prefer if it was also "as in speech".

Comment: I've used and enjoyed *Conversation* in Snow Leopard but I can't find a link right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Adium icon]

Try [Adium](http://adium.im/), which has [IRC support and a lot more](http://adium.im/help/pgs/Accounts-ListOfServices.html) all free and its still under active development. Also it supports Snow Leopard on the current 1.5.3 version, as long as your up to at least OS X 10.6.8.

> **Supported services**
>
> - XMPP ("Jabber"), including
>
>   - Google Talk
>   - LJ (LiveJournal) Talk
>   - Facebook Chat
>   - Gizmo5
> - MSN Messenger
> - AOL Instant Messenger (AIM), including
>
>   - MobileMe (formerly known as .Mac)
> - Yahoo! Messenger, including
>
>   - Yahoo! Japan Messenger
> - ICQ
> - Bonjour, compatible with iChat
> - Twitter
> - **IRC**
> - MySpaceIM
> - Gadu-Gadu
> - IBM Lotus Sametime
> - Novell GroupWise

Comment: Oh! I've always loved Adium, I had no idea it did IRC as well. I'll try to see how well he does it, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I use and quite like [LimeChat](http://limechat.net/mac/). Free as in beer and free as in speech. The latest release was 2.32 (2012.07.30) -- so it's getting actively developed. I was running it on Snow Leopard just fine. As well as Lion and now Mountain Lion. Snow Leopard is the minimum OS requirement for it.

As for the regular update request: Snow Leopard is getting on in age now. It's two minor versions behind Mountain Lion. Expect that development for this platform is going to taper off severely at this point in time. That's just how it goes. In the case of LimeChat, the 2.30 release support Snow Leopard and it got an update in January 2012. That's hardly a dead and abandoned code line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like they dropped Snow Leopard support (current version is 2.32, and the last supported by 10.6 is 2.30) :/

Comment: 2.30 was an update in 2012 as well. That's hardly a dead code line.

Answer (score 1):

Colloquy (http://colloquy.info/downloads.html) is actively developed, though not for Snow Leopard. There is an old version still available for 10.6.
[image: What you'll see most of the time.]
It's the only IRC client I've used for any length of time and it seems to do its job fairly well, though it certainly has some quirks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I asked this specifically because I'm using it and I can't stand anymore some bugs which won't be fixed. "Actively developed" was not an optional part of the question, at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KVIrc](http://www.kvirc.net/?id=releases&platform=macosx), it is free and it received an update recently

Answer (score 0):

[IRCCloud](https://www.irccloud.com/) is a web service with a free tier (iOS and Android apps too). As such, it's actively developed and will run on Snow Leopard.

I ‘wrap’ it in [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) for some desktop client features (notifications, unread badge, etc.).